# I am a bit confused with idempotent implementation for HTTP PUT/DELETE

Tags: http

HTTP PUT/DELETE are idempotent, so clients can make that same call repeatedly while producing the same result and should not have any side effects.
Is this just a rule/convention that the developers should follow?
In other words, are the developers responsible for ensuring their HTTP PUT/DELETE operations are idempotent? We can always make PUT/DELETE non-idempotent depending on how they set up the resource and implement it, correct?

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, are the developers responsible for ensuring their HTTP PUT/DELETE operations are idempotent?

Yes.